# how to draw these circles?

Tags: geometry, circles

How to draw these circles? I'm looking for a method which I can do it with Adobe Illustrator. (or draw in GeoGebra and export to illustrator)

[image]

(Adapted from [dribbble](http://dribbble.com/shots/185592-Industrial-01), created by [Olaf Muller](http://dribbble.com/olaf_muller).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lighter circles seem to have centers that lie on a common circle $S$, and have radii twice that of $S$.

In GeoGebra, try

```
sequence[circle[(cos(t),sin(t)),2],t,0,8,pi/3]
```

and fiddle with the details. The thicker circle that is concentric with the whole picture seems to have the same radius as the others, so you can tack on a

```
circle[(0,0),2]
```

The darker spirals are arcs of the circles that the code for the light circles produces. So try

```
sequence[arc[circle[(cos(t),sin(t)),2],(cos(t),sin(t))+2*(-sin(t),cos(t)),(-cos(t),-sin(t))],t,0,2*pi,pi/12]
```

Comment: wow! you're awesome! thank you so much..!

Comment: another question: is it possible to have more spirals in specific sections? please look at the picture. it has some more spirals in 4 sections.